# API based Webapplication Bad or Future Idea

Tags: php, api, web-applications

Is api based webapp better than classic one.Let me tell you a example suppose a I need to create a website which is user driven and image uploading and sharing based.

Will API will help to make it fast and make it more flexible.

As JSON data of files has to be parsed by front end Application and other works too.
Will that make frontend more slower or bulky.

I know multiple platforms application can be made using API but still i lack some of knowldege what and how WEBAPP based on API WORK. And is API based webapp is really necessary or the next future.

Comment: read about "api-first" movement, I much pref doing the API first, it's a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer api first.

If your web app uses ajax to save data you have to create the api anyway.

Here is an example: User fills out a form and presses save, if you do an ajax to save the form you basically need to implement an api. So better to think about it upfront.

Once you have a json api you can use it in other apps and platforms (say ios or android) too.